# Can't access methods in my subclasses

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, dynamic-arrays

So, I'm very close to finishing a project; however, I am trying to access methods in my Circle and Rectangle classes. My code thus far is :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class hw2redo 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

          GeometricObject g = null;
          File diskFile = new File("file.txt");
          Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(diskFile);
          ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
          while(diskScanner.hasNext()){
              String geolist = diskScanner.nextLine();
              g = recreateObject(geolist);

              list.add(g);

          }
          diskScanner.close();
         /* while (diskScanner.hasNext()) {
              String list = diskScanner.nextLine();
              g = recreateObject(list);
          }
          diskScanner.close();*/
          showObjects(list);
       }





    private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data) {

          String[] list = data.split(",");
          String geoObject = list[0];

          if (geoObject.equals("Circle")) {
             String color = list[1];
             boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]); 
             double radius = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
             return new Circle(radius, color, filled);
          }

          if (geoObject.equals("Rectangle")) {
             String color = list[1];
             boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]);
             double height = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
             double width = Double.valueOf(list[4]);
             return new Rectangle(width, height, color, filled);
          }
        return null;


       }
     private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list)
     {
         for(GeometricObject o : list)
            {

                 if(o.equals("Circle"))
                     printCircle();

            }
     }
    }
```

```
class GeometricObject {
       private String color = "white";
       private boolean filled;
       private java.util.Date dateCreated;
       private String data;

      /** Construct a default geometric object */
      public GeometricObject() {
     dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
     //this.data = data;
      }

     /** Construct a geometric object with the specified color
     * and filled value */
     public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
     dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
     this.color = color;
     this.filled = filled;
     }

     /** Return color */
     public String getColor() {
     return color;
     }

     /** Set a new color */
     public void setColor(String color) {
     this.color = color;
     }

     /** Return filled. Since filled is boolean,
     its getter method is named isFilled */
     public boolean isFilled() {
     return filled;
     }

     /** Set a new filled */
     public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
     this.filled = filled;
     }

     /** Get dateCreated */
     public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
     return dateCreated;
     }

     /** Return a string representation of this object */
     public String toString() {
     return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color +
     " and filled: " + filled;
     }
     }
```

```
class Circle extends GeometricObject
{
private double radius;

public Circle() {
}

public Circle(double radius) {
this.radius = radius;
}
public Circle(double radius,
String color, boolean filled) {
this.radius = radius;
setColor(color);
setFilled(filled);
}

/** Return radius */
public double getRadius() {
return radius;
}

/** Set a new radius */
public void setRadius(double radius) {
this.radius = radius;
}

/** Return area */
public double getArea() {
return radius * radius * Math.PI;
}

/** Return diameter */
public double getDiameter() {
return 2 * radius;
}

/** Return perimeter */
public double getPerimeter() {
return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
}

/** Print the circle info */
public void printCircle() {
System.out.println("The circle is created " + getDateCreated() +
" and the radius is " + radius);
}
}
```

```
class Rectangle extends GeometricObject {
private double width;
private double height;

public Rectangle() {
}

public Rectangle(
double width, double height) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

public Rectangle(
double width, double height, String color, boolean filled) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
setColor(color);
setFilled(filled);
}

/** Return width */
public double getWidth() {
return width;
}

/** Set a new width */
public void setWidth(double width) {
this.width = width;
}

/** Return height */
public double getHeight() {
return height;
}

/** Set a new height */
public void setHeight(double height) {
this.height = height;
}

/** Return area */
public double getArea() {
return width * height;
}

/** Return perimeter */
public double getPerimeter() {
return 2 * (width + height);
}
}
```

When i try to access the printCircle method in my Circle sub class, I recieve the error

> The method printCircle() is undefined for the type hw2redo

Any help or idea as to what I'm doing incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: What line, exactly, is giving you that error?

Comment: Sorry, definately should've crunched the code. It's in my showObjects method (third method down). @Michael

Comment: `printCircle()` is a method on `Circle`, not `GeometricObject`. Update this line: `for(GeometricObject o : list)`.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make two for each loops: one with Circle and the other with Rectangle instead of GeometricObject but then it says I can't convert from element type GeometricObject to Circle but I'm confused because my Circle class extends GeometricObject? @Eraph

Answer (score 2):

Just noticing this:`printCircle()` is a function of class `Circle`, so to access this method you'll need to call printCircle() on the object:

```
private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list) {
     for(GeometricObject o : list) {
             if(o.equals("Circle"))
                 (Circle) o.printCircle();
     }
}
```

Give this a try

Comment: Ahh! Casting did indeed remove the error, however; I'm not receiving any output?

Comment: I recommend adding some debug or print statements in your `recreateObject` method, perhaps a file you're reading is causing this function to return null?

Answer (score 0):

There a few different things that are wrong when you attempt to call `printCircle`. The major problem, and the one the compiler tries telling you, is that you are calling `printCircle` inside of the `hw2redo` class. That doesn't make sense; that method belongs in the `Circle` class. This is how I would fix your code. Judding from the fact that you only care about the `GeometricObject` when it's a circle, why even have that as your parameter? Change it to:

```
private static void showObjects(ArrayList<Circle> list){
    for(Circle c : list){
        c.printCircle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I need to do the same for my rectangle objects (I just decided i should figure out how to correctly get the circle to work). May i ask why calling it inside my hw2redo class is incorrect? Because i need to use one method to call my rectangle and circle methods. I was going to add a second if statement for rectangle once i figured out what the issue was for the circle method.

Comment: Because `printCircle` is not located in `hw2redo`, which is where you call it from. @RiFFRAFF

Comment: But then why can i access the toString Method in my GeometricObjects class?